# What does this LINQ to SQL error mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql

I'm getting the below error in my C#/ASP.NET project for some reason - presumably it's relating to the SubString part of the query. However, 'SageJobNo' and 'CutOffDate' are always populated.

Error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

And the code is below:

```
 IEnumerable<CcsVwICATimesheet> Timesheets = (from s in SageDC.CcsVwICATimesheets where s.Contract_Number.Substring(0, s.Contract_Number.IndexOf(" ")) == SageJobNo && s.Timesheet_Date <= CutOffDate select s);

    foreach (CcsVwICATimesheet Timesheet in Timesheets)
    {
         LabourCosts += (double)Timesheet.Cost_Value;
    }
```

EDIT: The error occurs on the 'foreach' line

Comment: The error is when the LINQ query is executed, are you sure that Contract_Number always contains a space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't have any `' '` in your string [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) will return -1 and Substring will fail.

**Edit**
You can safeguard by checking if the string contains `" "`.

```
IEnumerable<CcsVwICATimesheet> Timesheets = 
    (from s in SageDC.CcsVwICATimesheets 
        where 
        (
        (s.Contract_Number.Contains(" ") && s.Contract_Number.Substring(0, s.Contract_Number.IndexOf(" ")) == SageJobNo)
        ||
        (!s.Contract_Number.Contains(" ") && s.Contract_Number == SageJobNo)
        )
        && s.Timesheet_Date <= CutOffDate select s);
```

If you prefer the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) that could be used as well.

If you use Linq2Objects you can use `s.Contract_Number.Split().First()`, but LINQ can not translate that to SQL.

Comment: Ah I see, some contract numbers don't have spaces in. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @Chris, you need to check if the answer contains spaces before using IndexOf and Substring, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around the issue by using my substring at a fixed length.

```
IEnumerable<CcsVwICAPurchase> Purchases = (from s in SageDC.CcsVwICAPurchases where s.Contract_Number.Substring(0, Global.SageJobNoLength).Trim() == SageJobNo && s.Line_Type == "Materials" && s.Document_Date <= CutOffDate select s);
```